# Pass more than one variable to beforeSend function via $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following Ajax call:

```
function ajaxCall(soap, url){
    // Post SOAP request.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        data: soap,
        dataType: "xml",
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: passToProxy(url),
        success: onSuccess,
        error: function(){
            getRandom();
        }
    });
}

function passToProxy(xhr,url1) {
    alert(url1);
     // Pass the target URL onto the proxy.
     xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPTarget","http://localhost:8088/mockSDClientSOAPBinding");
     // Pass the action onto the proxy.
     xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","invoke");
}
```

I want to be able to pass the url variable to the passToProxy function (want to replace "http://localhost:8088/mockSDClientSOAPBinding" with a variable url), but I don't think I have the right idea here. The alert in passToProxy pops up "undefined." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the ajax call your only passing one parameter to the passToProxy function should you not be passing in two.  I.e is the url going inot the xhr object not the url1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){ passToProxy(xhr, url); }
```